# Avoid multiple executions of a function in different instances

Tags: php, database, wordpress, performance, plugins

**The scenario**

i have build a lottery as a wordpress plugin. Users register them self and with the first call to the site of the next day a winner is diced by the plugin. After that the winner is saved in a table.

To start the dicing again the plugin looks in a table if there is a winner for the day and should quit if it finds a winner.

This mechanism did work for all my tests and a few days in production but now for some reason the plugin produced 15 Winners in a timespan of three seconds. The logs showed no errors. I ve copied all the data to my staging environment and could not reproduce the behaviour.

**What might have happened**

I guess the server was under load (shared hosting) and there were several instances of wordpress that started dicing. After the first process wrote the winner to the database the dicing stopped.

**Possible solution**

I could write a file to the filesystem to avoid time consuming querys to the database so that other instances will know that there is a dicing going on and will exit the function.

I would be glad for any advice if i am on the right track or if i am thinking the wrong way.

I ve copied the critical functions below.

Starting the Plugin

```
$from = "2021-12-01 00:00:00";
$to = "2021-12-25 23:59:59";
$lottery = new Controller($from, $to);
```

The Controller

```
class Controller {
    private $_from;
    private $_to;

    public function __construct($from, $to) {
        $this->_from = new \DateTime($from, new \DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
        $this->_to = new \DateTime($to, new \DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
        add_action('init', array($this,'init'));
    }

    public function init() {
        $day = +date("j");
        $day--;

        $lastDiceDay = Model::getLastDiceDay();
        if ($lastDiceDay >= $day) {
            return;
        }

        $dateDay = new \DateTime($this->_from->format('Y-m') . "-$day");
        $mails = Model::getMailsByDay($dateDay);

        $winners = $this->dice($mails, $day);
        Model::saveWinner($winners, $day);
        $this->mail($winners, $day);
    }
...
}
```

Model Functions

```
class Model {

   public static function getLastDiceDay() {
       global $wpdb;
       $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT MAX(day_of_lottery) FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'lottery', ARRAY_A);

       if ($result) {
           return +reset($result[0]);
       } else {
        return null;
        }
    }
    public static function saveWinner($winners, $day) {
        global $wpdb;
        $count = count($winners);
        while ($count--) {
            $winner = $winners[$count]->mail;
            $row = ["winner_mail" => $winner["mail"], "time" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "day_of_lottery" => $day, "email_log_id" =>  $winner["id"]];
            $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'lottery', $row );
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The docs for [flock()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) or [sem_acquire()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-acquire.php) may help.

Comment: @Matt Raines: Semaphores sound very promissing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be to use a scheduled task (via cron for example) that runs once every day and draws the winner.

It could be an ajax endpoint you expose (then use a service to make a request to it every day), a Wordpress task (would require running wp_cron off a cron task to avoid race conditions like you have), or a file in your WP root directory that gets called from a cron task.

This way you're not relying on people visiting your site to trigger an important function. It could even run at 5 in the morning when there's no traffic.